# Android Animation not work when i call visibility

Tags: android, animation, visibility

The animation does not work after I set visibility to Invisible, I tried clear animation but not work. I have a button when I click the button it opens a linear layout with animation when I press back button I set the linear layout visibility to invisible again I click the button linear layout appear but no animation please help me.

```
l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrlgn);
  l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrlgn1);
  l2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  Animation  uptodown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.uptodown);
  viewcrrd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                l2.setAnimation(downtoup);

                l2.clearanimation(); // is it right ?

                l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
 public void onBackPressed() {
//        super.onBackPressed();

        if (back_pressed + TIME_DELAY > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
//            super.onBackPressed();
            Exitdlg alert = new Exitdlg();
            alert.showDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Are You Sure ");
            l2.clearAnimation();

        } else {

            l2.clearAnimation();


            l2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startAnimation` instead of `setAnimation`

```
 viewcrrd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             l2.clearanimation(); 

            l2.startAnimation(downtoup);

        }
    });
```